# if child exists

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make some CSS as dynamic as possible, but for the next I'm having some issues making it work:

Say I have the following html and css so far:

```css
nav.blended {
  color: red;
}
nav.blended + .optional-stuff {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav class="blended">
  <div class="substuff">
    should be green
  </div>
  <div class="optional-stuff">
    should be green
  </div>
</nav>

<nav class="blended">
  <div class="substuff">
    should be red
  </div>
</nav>
```

But now it always remains red.

codepen if needed: http://codepen.io/cskiwi/pen/GoRqPL?editors=110

Comment: Remove the `+` and it will work. + is used to select the sibling element and not child.

Comment: @ManojKumar this only make the second one green not the first one

Answer (score 0):

`.optional-stuff` is not siblings of `nav.blended`.

```css
nav.blended {
  color: red;
}
nav.blended .substuff + .optional-stuff {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav class="blended">
  <div class="substuff">
    should be green
  </div>
  <div class="optional-stuff">
    should be green
  </div>
</nav>

<nav class="blended">
  <div class="substuff">
    should be red
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: this only make the second one green not the first one

Comment: @Kiwi Do you want to change color of `substuff`?

Comment: no the other one that says `should be green`, for me your example has only 1 green

Comment: @Kiwi It is not possible by pure css. You have to use javascript or jquery.

Comment: @Kiwi Check [this](http://codepen.io/alireza-safian/pen/adbmzG?editors=101).

Comment: Damn, was hoping it was possible

Comment: There is no parent selector in css3. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) can help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96970/discussion-between-alireza-safian-and-kiwi).